Benefits of using toSignal instead of async pipe
For example, I need to fetch some data via http request and assign the received value somewhere in template. I would like to know which of the following solutions is better and whether there are advantages in using signals in such case?
export class MessagesComponent {
    private messages$ = this.messagesService.getMessages();
    public messages = toSignal(this.messages$);
 }

In template [items]="messages()"
export class MessagesComponent implements OnInit{
    public messages$: Observable<Tag[]>;
        
     ngOnInit() {
         this.messages$ = this.messagesService.getMessages();
     }
   }

In template [items]="messages$ | async"

I'd pick signal in any case even this simple one because

you now have to import the pipe to component
pretty sure doing messages$ | async in your template is not the only thing you gonna do but pretty sure you will want to show some text if there are no messages, you're going do something like (messages$ | async)?.length === 0 which will cause second request (first one is for your ngFor/@for loop to print the list and second one to handle empty list), you can workaround this by using as in ngIf/@if or by using share/shareReplay operator
there is also a difference like comparing ngIf and @if. @if works much faster because its handling is written directly in component's rendering compiled code whether ngIf will be handled inside of a directive that angular should go inside during change detection, etc, much more code to execute. Same for async pipe, angular should go inside pipe, run transform, detect changes whether observable is changed etc, too many runtime stuff, while signals are core functionality nowadays of a framework that should be handled closer to component rendering code than go inside pipe
you should keep in mind that signal based component is going to have advantage of view rerendering once dependent signal value is changed. So it means that when your messages will be fetched then only your view that uses messsages() will be rerendered. Currently change detection runs from root component aka AppComponent and goes deep in component tree change detecting things depending on dirty state. So it should increase potentially change detection time.

To recap: when using signals you do have a pretty minimalistic code that has no other pipes dependencies to make it work, it will not call multiple times your request if you want to use your signal multiple times in template, it's much more performant in case of change detection for your app

If you have data that is dependent on this.message$, signals are better.
messages = toSignal(this.messagesService.getMessages());
filteredMessages = computed(() => {
  return this.messages().filter(value => value.role === 'admin' /* for example */
}));

if you had to do this purely with observables, you would need either two subscriptions, a share, some pipe(maps), multiple properties.. or other stuff.. It would not be hard to do, but signals are preferable and easier to reason about in said cases. As a bonus, you don't need the AsyncPipe import if trying to cut down component sizes (to import pieces instead of CommonModule, using standalone, etc).
I would also argue that the Angular team is moving that way, so it should be a good idea to use signals when possible, just for the sake of maintainability.

In my case I just fetch data initially and that's all. So, maybe async pipe will be better here and code more readable? I can write in ngOnIinit smth like loadMessages();

I'd say it's preference then. I think you can actually assign the value from the service without ngOnInit. and that'd be way more readable. So if your use case is only that, I'd agree.. and if it becomes complex, migrating to signals is seamless, so both should be in the back of the mind if that makes sense
